# Is it possible to detect box failure using Geneos from ITRS?

Tags: monitoring, geneos, itrs

Is it possible to detect that a Windows Server box is not responsive or has gone down (shut down, crashed etc.) using Geneos from ITRS? My main aim is to detect that a box isn't responsive and take corrective action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `desktop-pc-monitoring` plug-in available in geneos samplers. It will show you something like this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this does not go down to the level of service monitoring or does it?

Comment: No it doesn't. But you can use win-services plug-in for services monitoring.

Comment: Great. If you add that as an answer I will accept that. Thanks.